# Cakephp - search by field of different table

Tags: php, cakephp, search, cakephp-1.3

I have two tables:

1. evaluation_employees
   Fields: id, username
2. evaluation_results
   Fields: id, grade, evaluation_employee_id

In evaluation_results view I need to search the results (using the [cakephp search plugin](http://cakedc.com/downloads/view/cakephp_search_plugin)) by the employee's username, but in evaluation_results table I have the employee's id(evaluation_employee_id), not the username. I don't know how to make a link between those tables, to make it work.

Code in my view (evaluation_results/index.ctp):

```
echo $this->Form->create('EvaluationResult', array(
            'url' => array_merge(array('action' => 'index'), $this->params['pass'])
            ));
echo $this->Form->input('username', array('div' => false, 'empty' => true)) . '<br/><br/>';
echo $this->Form->submit(__('Search', true), array('div' => false));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Code in my controller (evaluation_results_controller.php):

```
var $components = array('Search.Prg');
    function index() {
        $this->Prg->commonProcess();
        $this->EvaluationResult->recursive = 0;
        $this->paginate = array(
                    'conditions' => $this->EvaluationResult->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs));
        $this->set('evaluationResults', $this->paginate());
    }
```

Code in my model (evaluation_result.php):

```
public $actsAs = array('Search.Searchable');

    //Search fields data description for processing.
    public $filterArgs = array(
        array('name' => 'EvaluationEmployee.username', 'type' => 'query', 'method' => 'filterUsername')
    );

    //Method as decalred in $filterArgs to process the free form search.
    public function filterUsername($data, $field = null) {
        if (empty($data['EvaluationEmployee']['username'])) {
            return array();
        }
        $username = '%' . $data['EvaluationEmployee']['username'] . '%';
        return array(
                $this->alias . '.EvaluationEmployee.username LIKE' => $username
            );
    }
```

Please tell me if more info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up the associations in the model it will find all related records automatically when you search for an employee.

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together